# external link with hashtag delay the scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, hashtag

I'm working on a portfolio site that has to be put on a site containing 2 frames (can't change that however)

It has a left frame which contains the links, and a right frame which contains the content itself. The links on the left frame all have a hashtag in their url #. So i can use a single page layout, i already made it so that your current position is saved when you reload the page and that you go back to your last position. This is so i can let the user reload the page without notifying it that much, and once loaded the page will scroll to their chosen link(anchor)

What i do need to do now is preventing scrolling to the position of the anchor, atleast until the page is fully loaded and when the previous position is restored.

Does someone know a way to do this? I heard someone say i could use something he calls altering the hash tag scheme, but i can't seem to find it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind to prevent a link to take you to a new URL is the [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/). You may want to put it in the click event of those links.

Comment: @KevinCittadini the problem is that i can't set a click event on the left-frame links. (don't have access to it)

Comment: I found the issue causing the difference why it works or why not. 

It seems that the frame reloads when the domain name is different (http://www.page.com will reload the browser if you click on a link which is http://page.com) 

Otherwise it won't reload but doesn't smoothly scroll to anchor either. While all the other links do inside the content frame. Link frame does not

Answer (score 0):

Use window load event in jquery.

```
$(window).load(function(){
   // Put your code here
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you just made me think of something. 
This seems to work too. 


      `var loadedhash = window.location.hash;
    window.location.hash = "";`

Comment: Nevermind, when reloading the page it prevents the scrolling to the anchor. 

However when you just type the url in your browser (new session) it shows you the anchor like it would normally

Comment: what happens now is that when you visit page.com/#anchor1 it prevents the page from scrolling to anchor position. But when you click on a new link say page.com/#anchor2 it doesn't load the correct anchor (the variable which loads the # value is empty the second time)